# WCF Timeouts larger than configured

Tags: c#, wcf, timeout, nettcpbinding

I have configured my wcf with these timeouts:

```
  public static NetTcpBinding MakeTcpBinding(bool isClient)
  {
     return new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, false)
     {
        HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
        TransactionFlow = false,
        PortSharingEnabled = true,
        Security = {Transport = {ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None}},
        ReceiveTimeout = isClient ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) : TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        SendTimeout = isClient ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
        ListenBacklog = int.MaxValue,
        MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
        MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288,
        ReaderQuotas =
        {
           MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue,
           MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue,
           MaxDepth = int.MaxValue,
           MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue,
           MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue
        }
     };
  }
```

Which should set the imeout to 1 second when a client connects to a non-existing server.

However, when actually calling open, I see a 21 second timeout.

> DEBUG 2013-07-31 18:12:44,712 Communication.WcfCommunicator -
>   NotifyAllReceivers: Type: AskWhoIsAwake, SentDate: 7/31/2013 18:12:44
>   AM, DetectSessionId: 37106dee-b563-458b-9eb7-a90e81f82563 - 1
>
> DEBUG 2013-07-31 18:13:05,746 Communication.WcfCommunicator - Could not connect to 
>   net.tcp://notup/xxx.svc/motup_www-xxx-com. The connection attempt
>   lasted for a time span of 00:00:00.9879988. TCP error code 10060: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond 42.42.42.42:808.  - 6

What is causing the extra 20 second timeout?

Comment: How do you compute the 21 second timeout? I see that `The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:00.9879988` so the transport raised the connection exception after 987 ms (very close to 1 second) which is somewhat what you expect

Comment: timestamp shows 21 seconds difference though

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Client ignores timeout values when service down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902985/wcf-client-ignores-timeout-values-when-service-down)

Comment: also, ReceiveTimeout = isClient ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) : TimeSpan.FromDays(1), --> 1 day!?

Comment: I want the client to timeout fast, but the server shouldnt drop an inactive connection... ReceiveTimeout means two different things depending on it being the client or server configured with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using the async open and setting timeout.

```
     var ar = client.InnerChannel.BeginOpen(null, null);
     if (!ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout, true))
        throw new CommunicationException("Service is not available");
     client.InnerChannel.EndOpen(ar);
```